# How do I tell juju to use the liberty release of Openstack in Trusty 14.04.3

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

This is probably a dumb question, but I can't figure out how to tell juju to use the liberty version of Openstack charms when deploying on Trusty.

I already have the liberty cloud archive installed on my maas controller:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If anyone else has this same problem, I found the answer in the 15.10 release notes:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackCharms/ReleaseNotes1510#OpenStack_Liberty_support_for_14.04_and_15.10

Basically you can either put it in the openstack-config.yaml for each service with:

```
nova-cloud-controller:
  openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
```

or set it manually with:

```
juju set keystone openstack-origin='cloud:trusty-liberty'
```

More information is in the link.